# Chrome default Date picker. black bar along bottom when switching to month with 31 days

Tags: forms, google-chrome, input, datepicker

I am using the following input:

```
<input type="date" class="frequency required" id="until_date" name="until_date">
```

and I have noticed the following issue with the browsers default date picker in Chrome.

.

[image: Chrome Date picker issue]

The issue seen in the image is the black bar along the bottom of the date picker and the rest of the contents shifted upwards.

This happens when switching to a month with 31 days using the arrow buttons in the top right of the date picker.

Every time a there is a month with 31 days another bar gets added to the bottom. After 2 black bars the date picker arrows get hidden and are no longer clickable.

Any ideas on what is causing this problem and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read up on details of the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374705

The issue comes up when the Chrome date picker is forced to open upwards instead of downwards due to the calendar control being near the bottom of the viewport or screen.  If you can scroll up so the control has room to open downwards the issue will resolve itself temporarily.

There is little we Chrome users can do to actually solve the issue other than wait.  I'm running 40.0.2214.111 and the issue is still present.  The good news is Chrome Canary has this issue resolved so it's just a waiting game on the fix to make its way through the codebase and hopefully will be included before the main branch makes it to version 42.0.2300.2 (the current Canary version).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version 40+?  I updated last night and am noticing the same issue, though I did not notice the issue prior to the update.  I reported the issue through Chrome's issue report/filer utility in Settings.

Comment: I am using Version 40.0.2214.111 m.